# Access search function: Display "No Match" if no records found

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

I have a search function implemented in my Access form. A user can search to see if there is an existing entry. I want to make it so that there will be a display of "No match found" if the user searches and no existing entry.

Below is my VBA code so far:

```
Private Sub Command49_Click()
Dim strsearch As String
Dim strtext As String
strtext = Me.txtSearch.Value
strsearch = "SELECT * from ID_Theft_Log where (ID like strtext)"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub
```

What do I need to add to my code to display that text?

Comment: you could use if dcount..... =0 then not bother with the SQL setting, or look at the records returned from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF strsearch.value = VbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End if
```